# What does the /^ symbol mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

A friend of mine is trying to explain to me the answer to this problem:

> Define a method binary_multiple_of_4?(s) that takes a string and returns true if the string represents a binary number that is a multiple of 4.

However, his example he gave is this:

```
if (s) == "0"
    return true
end
if /^[01]*(00)$/.match(s) #|| /^0$/.match(s)
    return true
else
    return false
end
```

It works, because the software we use says there were no errors, but I don't understand why, or what /^ means, and how it's used.

If you could also explain the /^0$/.match(s), that would be great too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

what he is doing is using regular expressions, see: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm

To break it down, there is a pattern that is matched inside the slashes `/pattern/` and every character means something. `^` means start of the line `[01]` means match a `0` or a `1`, `*` means match the previous thing (`[01]`) zero or more times, and `(00)` means match `00`, and `$` means match the end of the line.

If you want to know what /^0$/ matches, you should definitely try to figure it out based on the information in my post or the link I provided. Here's the answer though (hover to view):

> It matches the beginning of the line, zero, the end of a line.

Comment: `[01]` means a 0 or a 1, it is a character class and is exactly the same as `[10]`